# Are the quotes mentioned relating to weapons similar to nuclear weapons correct translations?

Tags: india, hinduism

These are some quotes by Hindus which suggest that there were mentions of nuclear weapons in Ancient India.

These are copy and pasted across many sites without citing sources or telling us where it is from.

I'm asking for multiple quotes which are not mentioned in the other question and asking for their authenticity and not if nuclear weapons existed.

https://mathildasweirdworldweblog.wordpress.com/2008/05/17/a-nuclear-bomb-in-the-ancient-hindu-text-the-mahabharata/

1) Do these quotes even exist in the Mahabaratha?

2) If they do, are these correct translations?

3) What is the source translation of these quotes?

4) What is the original translation for these texts for example the one in http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/maha/ ?

If you think this question has something bad and is against the rules edit it.

> Gurkha, flying a swift and powerful vimana hurled a single projectile
>   charged with the power of the Universe. An incandescent column of
>   smoke and flame, as bright as ten thousand suns, rose with all its
>   splendor.
>
> It was an unknown weapon, an iron thunderbolt, a gigantic messenger of
>   death, which reduced to ashes the entire race of the Vrishnis and the
>   Andhakas.
>
> The corpses were so burned as to be unrecognizable. Hair and nails
>   fell out; Pottery broke without apparent cause, and the birds turned
>   white.
>
> ...After a few hours all foodstuffs were infected... ...to escape from
>   this fire the soldiers threw themselves in streams to wash themselves
>   and their equipment."
>
> Dense arrows of flame, like a great shower, issued forth upon
>   creation, encompassing the enemy... A thick gloom swiftly settled upon
>   the Pandava hosts. All points of the compass were lost in darkness.
>   Fierce wind began to blow upward, showering dust and gravel.
>
> Birds croaked madly... the very elements seemed disturbed. The earth
>   shook, scorched by the terrible violent heat of this weapon. Elephants
>   burst into flame and ran to and fro in a frenzy... over a vast area,
>   other animals crumpled to the ground and died. From all points of the
>   compass the arrows of flame rained continuously and fiercely. "

This is another quote.

https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-incidents-of-nuclear-war-or-nuclear-weapons-used-in-ancient-India

> "A single projectile charged with all the power in the Universe…An
>   incandescent column of smoke and flame as bright as 10,000 suns, rose
>   in all its splendor…it was an unknown weapon, an iron thunderbolt, a
>   gigantic messenger of death which reduced to ashes an entire race.
>
> "The corpses were so burned as to be unrecognizable. Their hair and
>   nails fell out, pottery broke without any apparent cause, and the
>   birds turned white.
>
> "After a few hours, all foodstuffs were infected. To escape from this
>   fire, the soldiers threw themselves into the river

Comment: @Avery I changed the question to check authenticity of specific quotes

Comment: There's an answer to your more specific question here: http://www.jasoncolavito.com/uploads/3/7/5/9/3759274/colavito_-_ancient_atom_bombs.pdf Sorry that I don't have time to summarize right now, but I have read the entire first half of the Mahabharata and I can confirm that the poor folks who make this quotation have never heard or read the poem!!